# When Passing Range object to a function as a single argument throws error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm just curious to know what is going on here and  what am I doing wrong?

> Case 1:
>
> When Passing Only Range object as an argument throws - Object Require Error

Sample Code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("Project")
ws.Activate

Set rng = Range("A1:A12")
passRange(rng)   ' Throws Runtime error 
End Sub

Function passRange(rnge As Range)
MsgBox rnge.count
End Function
```

> Case 2,
>
> When passing 2 arguments it works just fine.

Sample Code:

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range
Dim IL As Long
IL = 12

Set ws = Worksheets("Project")
ws.Activate

Set rng = Range("A1:A12")
Call passRange(rng, IL)
End Sub

Function passRange(rnge As Range, IL As Long)
MsgBox rnge.count
End Function
```

Comment: While I dont have excel, one difference I can see is usage of `call` in `Call passRange(rng, IL)` whereas you aren't using it in 1st example.

Comment: The issue is not passing on or two argument! If you are passing arguments using Call then you must use parentheses around them. And in the other case you must not.

Comment: @Storax Invoking the function works just fine with the syntax employed by the OP, even when using the `Call` statement. @Hola I suppose you forgot to delete the second parameter in the function when testing the function call with just one parameter. This would indeed throw an exception in the first case, but not the second. Please see my answer.

Comment: @Miqi180: I think the TO just provided two different examples. `Call passRange(rng)`will also work in the first example. And for the second example `passRange rng, IL`is valid while `passRange(rng, IL)`will not work.

Comment: @Storax I tested both examples with and without the `Call` statement on my computer and indeed the second throws an exception without the `Call` statement, but since he writes that the **first** example (not the second) causes a run-time error my guess is still that the OP forgot to update the parameters of the function when he tested it the second time. Anyway, it's hard to know since he's being silent on this...

Comment: In `Function passRange(rnge As Range)` `rnge` is called `ByRef` as that's the default when not specified.  Using `passRange(rng)` overrides the `ByRef` with `ByVal` which passes the default property of `rng` ie `rng.Value` which is a type missmatch and causes the runtime error.  Note that `passRange(rng)` is valid syntax and hence no compile error.  Conflating this with the use of `Call` just confused the issue.  The equivalent of `passRange(rng)` using `Call` would be`Call passRange((rng))`.  The correct usage is example 1: `passRange rng` and example 2: `passRange rng, IL`.

Comment: Note that `Call` is obsolete and should _never_ be used.  Claims that it makes code easier to read are IMHO wrong

Comment: @Storax What I know is that if you pass more than more than 1 argument to a function enclosed with the parenthesis then only call keyword is required before the function.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't required to use the Call keyword when calling a procedure. However, if you use the Call keyword to call a procedure that requires arguments, argumentlist must be enclosed in parentheses. If you omit the Call keyword from the procedure call, you must also omit the parentheses around argumentlist.

See [here](https://www.engram9.info/visual-basic-vba/call-statement.html)

Exmple code how you have to use ist

```
Sub testSub(rg As Range)

End Sub

Sub TestItA()

Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1")

    testSub rg
    Call testSub(rg)
    testSub (rg)  'will throw a run time error
    call testsub  rg    ' will even not compile

End Sub


Function testFunc(rg As Range)

End Function

Sub TestIt()
Dim rg As Range
    Set rg = Range("A1")

    testFunc rg
    Call testFunc(rg)
    testFunc (rg)  'will throw a run time error
    call testfunc rg    ' will even not compile

End Sub
```

Comment: The way `passRange` is called, one should a) use a normal **`Sub`** instead of a function or b) define a return value to the function. 
In the latter case one could use an assignment to a declared variable, e.g. `myRngNumber = passRange(rng)` (no difference whether one or more arguments), or 
simply refer to the return value, e.g. via `Debug.print passRange(rng)`.

Comment: I think for the TO's question it does not make much of a difference if you have a function or a sub. Even if the function returns a value you can call it without assigning it to a variable (though it does not make that much sense) and in such a case you have to omit the parenthesis if you do not use `Call`

Comment: I agree with all your comment; just wanted to point out the customary use of a function (possibly not entirely clear to Hola). Of course it's necessary to use the correct calls you described taking care of parenthese setting: `testFunc rg` or `Call testFunc(rg)` :-)

Comment: @Storax @T.M.   Now, I'm getting more confused, try to pass variable of any data type except the object type.  `Dim IL as Integer`  `testFunct (IL)`  or `call testFunct (IL)`  this will work just fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to pass one **or** two parameters to the function, it should be rewritten like this:

```
Function passRange(rnge As Range, Optional IL As Long)
MsgBox rnge.count
End Function
```

Otherwise, it'll throw an exeption when only one parameter is passed. Alternatively, you could make both parameters optional.